# SQL - Transposing rows from some columns in a table to each record in thesame table

Tags: sql

I am using a platform which accepts minimal SQL functions to write a SQL code. The UNPIVOT function cannot be used on the platform so I have to do this manually. I am thinking along the line of UNION ALL and then CROSS JOINING (which I attempted but ended up with the wrong record counts. Please see image attached.

Any help / pointer will be highly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What DBMS are you using ..? (un)pivoting might change specific to DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `cross join`, but it requires some `case` logic.  The exact syntax depends on the database, but something like this:

```
select t.col1, t.col2,
       (case when n.n = 1 then t.col3 else t.col4 end) as newcol
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) n;
```

To load another table, you would do one of the following:

- `insert` these results into a table that has already been created.
- Use `select into` or `create table as` depending on the database.

If you care about the ordering, then you can add `order by t.col1, t.col2, n.n`.

In most cases, a simple `union all` approach is fine (such as GMB suggests).   That approach requires scanning the table twice, which incurs some additional overhead.  However, if the "table" is really a complex query or view, then only processing it once is a bigger advantage.

Comment: Please explain why this is downvoted.  It is an accurate answer to the question, unless I missed something.

Comment: Thanks for this. What would be the modification to your code given the additional columns you will find in the 2nd attachment beneath the original one? This is for a scenario where you have more than 2/3 columns of table1 you want to keep  and more than 3 columns of table1 you want to cross apply like above.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you used `UNION ALL` but it can be done like this:

```
select col1, col2, col3 as NewCol from Table1
union all
select col1, col2, col4 from Table1
```

You could also use an `ORDER BY` clause, so that rows with the same `col1` and `col2` appear in subsequent rows:

```
select col1, col2, NewCol
from (
  select col1, col2, col3 as NewCol, 1 as ord from Table1
  union all
  select col1, col2, col4, 2 from Table1
) t
order by col1, col2, ord
```

Answer (score 2):

A portable approach uses `union all`:

```
select col1, col2, col3 as newcol from mytable
union all
select col1, col2, col4 from mytable
```

If your database supports lateral joins (also called `cross apply` in some databases) and `values()`, this can be simplified:

```
select t.col1, t.col2, x.newcol
from mytable t
cross join lateral (values(col3), (col4)) x(newcol)
```